# How to detect file activities of exec'ed child process on Linux in C?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, child-process

I have my program, which exec's another process (not mine, consider it a blackbox). Is there a way to detect operations, like `open()` and `close()`, for this child process?

Especially I'm interested in finding all newly created files, or existing files, that are opened with intention to be created (`O_CREAT` flag for `open()`).

Comment: You might like to have a look at `man ptrace`. Or to catch the calls to `open()` done by the program directly you could write a replacement function to `open()` that logs each calls and then calls the "real" `open()` and put the wrapper into a lib and use `LS_PRELOAD` to have this lib loaded prior to the program.

Comment: @alk: good ideas, but that's `LD_PRELOAD` instead of `LS_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Yes sure, it's `LD_PRELOAD`. Sry for the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working approach is to redefine the `open()` within my own shared library and preload it inside `exec()`'ed process via `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable. Thanks to @alk for the approach.

The code for redefined `open()` looks like:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

extern "C" {

int open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...) {
  bool has_mode = false;
  mode_t mode = 0;
  if (flags & O_CREAT) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, flags);
    mode = va_arg(ap, mode_t);
    has_mode = true;
    va_end(ap);
  }

  using Fn = int (*)(const char * pathname, int flags, ...);
  Fn new_open = reinterpret_cast<Fn>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"));

  // Do something useful.

  if (has_mode) {
    return new_open(pathname, flags, mode);
  } else {
    return new_open(pathname, flags);
  }
}

}  // extern "C"
```

The only problem is with `fcntl.h` - it may have some geeky declaration for the function `open()`. You need this file to get definition of the `O_CREAT`. Another way is to include the file with definition directly: in my case it's the file `asm-generic/fcntl.h`.